# How to enable only week first day in bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker v3.0. How to enable only week first day in bootstrap datetimepicker?

**Expected result:**

[image]

Comment: Can you link the datetimepicker that you are using? Moreover show the code you used when you tried to disable some days in your datetimepicker component.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution for the same using moment js config.

```
//Set monday start week day

        moment.updateLocale('en', {
            week: {
                dow: 1 // Monday is the first day of the week
            }
        });

        jQuery('#meet_start_date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        })
```